# static files arent working in django, but i have the same settings as another project I have done in the past?

Tags: python, django

DEVELOPMENT SERVER - Can't get my static files to work(CSS), I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but I cant seem to get them to load at all.

my HTML template

```py
 {% load static %}
<link type="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'main.css' %}" />
```

Settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [


"C:/Users/Sam/Documents/Django/Blog/OrapiApplied/static"
]
```

My file layout

```py
/letsdoit
  manage.py
  /app
    /static
      main.css
  /letsdoit 
    settings.py
```

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIR` doesn’t seem to match your project name `letsdoit`.

Comment: you don't need STATICFILES_DIRS because you static files are in the static directory of your app, which django will look for anyway. As long as you have "django.contrib.staticfiles" in your INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

The setting is [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS), with an S.

Comment: true, but since OP's static dir is the default location Django looks for, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add **"django.contrib.staticfiles"** to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in settings.py, the Django `runserver` development server will automatically look for all `static` directories in all your apps.

If you also have static files in other locations (e.g. if you were to add a `static` directory inside `/letsdoit/letsdoit/` which is not an app), you'd have to add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS` so that Django also finds those.

Note that it's good pratice to namespace your static files for each app:

```
/app
  /static
    /app
      image.jpeg
```

So that way you can add `{% static 'app/image.jpeg' %}` in your template and for a different app you'd be able to also have a **image.jpeg** which wouldn't conflict with the one in `app`: `{% static 'other_app/image.jpeg' %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and don't forget to ***clear*** cached images and data of browser before loading the page. Sometimes the browser just keeps giving the browser CSS from the cache.